# Prolog: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file procedure `(?-A)' does not exist

Tags: prolog

I am trying to run the following code on SWI prolog:

```
prefix(Xs, Ys) :- append(Ys, _, Xs)
suffix(Xs, Ys) :- append(_, Ys, Xs)
sublist(Xs, Ys) :- suffix(Xs, Zs), prefix(Zs, Ys)
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error: Unexpected end of file
procedure `(?-A)' does not exist
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Each rule must be finished with a dot. Thus `prefix(Xs, Ys) :- append(Ys, _, Xs).` Also, you probably need to put the rules into a file and then say `[file].`

Answer (score 0):

Like what [false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165087/prolog-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-procedure-a-does-not-exist#comment106414693_60165087) said, you must end every rule with a dot.

```
prefix(Xs, Ys) :- append(Ys, _, Xs).
suffix(Xs, Ys) :- append(_, Ys, Xs).
sublist(Xs, Ys) :- suffix(Xs, Zs), prefix(Zs, Ys).
```